# Sending text messages via GMail in c#

Tags: c#, sms, gmail

I'm trying to make [this code](http://joelbennett.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/sending-text-messages-via-sms-to-a-mobile-phone-from-a-c-windows-application-via-gmail/) work, but it doesn't seems to work.

When I send an email to NUMBER@teletip.com (instead of this line in the code: `message.To.Add("1234567890@teletip.com");`), it only shows it in the 'sent items' label. But when I send SMS in the Google chat interface it works great. BTW, it also shows it in the 'sent items' label.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: does this NUMBER@teletip.com mail exist? Try to send to your private mail or some other known and see if it works...

Comment: what do you mean 'if this mail exist'

Comment: when i send message from the gmail chat to cellular phone

Comment: it's shows in the 'sent items' mail who sent to NUMBER@teletip.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what teletip.com is, but I can send text messages to my phone with the address `NUMBER@vtext.com` (Verizon); other carriers have other domains, I would start by finding out the domain for your phone and testing it that way.  [SMS411.net](http://sms411.net/how-to-send-email-to-a-phone/) has a list of domains for different carriers in the US and Canada.

Comment: teletip.com it's service that google use for sending sms worlwide via gmail

Comment: there is other domian for users from out of canada/usa ?

Answer (score 0):

For ATT Wireless in US it is: number@txt.att.net